# Set theoretic difference $A-B$ contradicting $\emptyset \in B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set theoretic difference is defined as follows:

> Let $A,B$ be sets. Then the set theoretic difference of $A,B$ (written $A- B$) is the set defined by:
>
> $x \in A-B$ iff $x \in A$  and $x \notin B$

In the notes I'm studying, I came across an example that $\mathbb{N} - \mathbb{Z}=\emptyset$. I realize that the point they're trying to get across is that the natural numbers are contained in the integers, but isn't it true that the empty set is in all sets? If so, does this not mean that $\emptyset \in A$ and $\emptyset \in B$, which contradicts the definition?

Sorry if this is too simple a question.

Comment: Do you know the difference between $\emptyset $ and $\{ \emptyset \}$?

Comment: Just that one is a set and the second is set containing the empty set

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The empty set is not an *element* of either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.  The empty set is a *subset* of both (and, indeed, any set).  Symbolically,
$$ \emptyset \not\in \mathbb{N},\quad \emptyset\not\in\mathbb{Z},
\qquad\text{but}\qquad
\emptyset \subseteq \mathbb{N}, \quad \emptyset\subseteq\mathbb{Z}. $$

Comment: In the usual set-theoretic definition of the natural numbers, $\emptyset$ _is_ in fact an element of $\mathbb{N}$, since $0 = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh! So then in order for a set to have contained in it the empty set, it must be explicitly written? For example let $ A =$ {$\emptyset,1,2,3,4,5$}. Then in this case, $\emptyset \in A$ **and** {$\emptyset$} $\subset A$?

Comment: @LucaBressan It depends on what model you use.  It is possible to define the natural axiomatically, in which case the emptyset needn't be an element of $\mathbb{N}$.  Also, $0$ is not a natural number. :P

Comment: @DarpanGanatra Your example is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am aware that there are many possible choices for $\mathbb{N}$, that is precisely why I wrote "the _usual_ set-theoretic definition". Also, $0$ is considered by many, if not most, mathematicians to be a natural number, e.g. in Peano arithmetic.

Comment: I guess it's fair to specify, "using the usual set-theoretic definition of zero". Once we progress past first principles, zero gets defined in plenty of other ways, such as "the equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rationals that are eventually smaller in absolute value than every positive epsilon"...

Comment: @LucaBressan First off, I am aware of the usual set-theoretic definition of the natural numbers.  However, in this context it seems clear that this is not the model under consideration.  If it were, then $\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ should be $\mathrm{N}$, since the set of integers, being equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers, contains no natural numbers.  As to whether or not zero is a natural number, I was being somewhat facetious (hence the emoticon), but it should be noted that the inclusion of zero is, while common, both recent (Bourbaki and later) and at all not universal.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the empty set is a subset of both the naturals and the integers. Indeed, it is the subset of the naturals containing all natural numbers that are not also integers.

It does not show up as an *element* of either the naturals or the integers, although it is an element of the power sets of both. If we were looking for $\mathcal P(\Bbb N) - \mathcal P(\Bbb Z)$, the empty set would not be an element of that difference, because it is in both. However, the empty set would *be* that difference, because there is no subset of $\Bbb N$ that is not also a subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Does that help to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The empty set is a subset of A and B not necessarily an element of A or B. The empty set belongs to A - B if and only if it belongs to A and does not belong to B. In your case of A = N and B = Z the set A-B is the empty set because there is no element of N which does not belong to Z.